# Android : How to start service for Alarm?

Tags: android, android-service

If I'am listening the phone call state then am writing one receiver and am mentioning that receiver in the manifest like this.

```
 <receiver android:name="com.domyhome.broadcastreceiver.IncomingCallInterceptor" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

In Intent filter I have given the `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE`. So based on this automatically it will perform the operation what i have done in my receiver.

In my application am getting data from the server by using Gcm. There is a data which have a date and time. So I want to make alarm based on the data where am getting from the server. It should happen when date and time matches with the device date and time. For this I have written the receiver.

But I don't know from where should i start the service. Because it should also run when my application is not in use.

I have written like this.

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.domyhome.broadcastreceiver.AlarmReceiver">
</receiver>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
```

AlarmReceiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method s
    List<CalEvent> cts;
    cts = CalEvent.listAll();
    CalEvent cal;
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    for(int i=0;i<cts.size();i++)
    {
        cal = cts.get(i);
        if(date.equals(cal.event_start))
        {
            generateNotification(context,"Hi how are you?",cal.event_start);
        }
    }
 }

private void generateNotification(Context context, String message, String time) {
    NotificationManager  mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
                .setContentTitle("Reminder")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Event"))
                .setContentText(time)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" +R.raw.sounds1));
 }
```

Please could anyone give me an idea?

Comment: Do you want to start service from onReceive() or when user clicks on notification?

Comment: @VikaL. I want to start service from onReceive()

Comment: So, what is the problem? You can start service from onReceive like this
 
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourService.class);        
context.startService(intent);

Do not forget to add service to the AndroidManifest